# Subtracting elements in a matrix

Tags: matrix, syntax, stata

I have a matrix in Stata like this:

```
matrix B = J(1,10,.)
```

I have defined the elements inside the matrix like this:

```
matrix B[1,2] = 5
matrix B[1,4] = 10
```

Now, I want to subtract two elements in the matrix and store the result as a different element:

```
matrix B[1,7] = matrix B[1,2] - matrix B[1,4]
```

but this doesn't work in Stata.

How can I subtract elements in Stata?

Comment: Getting started with code formatting is easy and a good idea to make your questions easier to read (and appear more serious). To get a line of code to show up as such, indent four spaces. For much more, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
. matrix B = J(1,10,.)

. matrix B[1,2] = 5 

. matrix B[1,4] = 10 

. matrix B[1,7] = B[1,2] - B[1,4] 

. matrix list B 

B[1,10]
     c1   c2   c3   c4   c5   c6   c7   c8   c9  c10
r1    .    5    .   10    .    .   -5    .    .    .
```

`matrix` here is a command. So, it doesn't belong in any expressions you feed to it. That's tacit in `help matrix operators` and `help matrix subscripting` which together document what you need.

Comment: Thank you! If I'm going for absolute differences, can I do this: abs[B[1,2] - B[1,4]]

Comment: `search absolute` or `help abs()` to find out.